# How to initialize non-const member variable with const value

Tags: c++, initialization

```cpp
struct IntSlice {
  int* ptr_;
  int  len_;
};

std::initializer_list<int> xs = {1, 2, 3};
const IntSlice s = {xs.begin(), (int)xs.size()}; // this does not work :(
```

It is giving me an error, that we cannot assign a const pointer to a non const pointer but I thought the declaration `const IntSlice` would fix that.

I think I know what's going on. `const IntSlice` is promoting `int* ptr_` to `int* const ptr_` not `const int* const ptr_` which is what I want.

But surely, there has to be some way to promote `int* ptr_` to `const int*` without having to create a `ReadonlyIntSlice`?

Comment: On another note, almost always when you feel the need to do a C-style cast, you should take that as a sign that you're probably doing something wrong. Why are you using a signed data-type for the length attribute?

Comment: The problem is that while the object `s` itself is `const` and can't be modified after initialization, the member variable `ptr_` is not a `const int*`. Making the structure itself `const` doesn't change the member variables const-qualifier status (then you could remove `const` qualifiers from member variables by simply declaring the structure object as non-constant).

Comment: While I don't expect negative lengths I find it convenient to use signed arithmetic. I don't expect the length to exceed it's representable range.

Comment: "without having to create a ReadonlyIntSlice” yes, create `Slice<T>`, good for `int`, `const int` or anything else.

Comment: Ah, ok. You put the const qualifier in front of the type argument. Perfect thanks! You should post this as answer because this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IntSlice` is too specific. It works only with (mutable) `int` slices. Why not have something that works with any type of slice?

```
template <typename T>
struct Slice
{
   T*          ptr_;
   std::size_t len_;
};
```

Now you can have `Slice<int>`, `Slice<const int>`, `Slice<const * const double>` and whatever else you fancy.

```
std::initializer_list<int> xs = {1, 2, 3};
Slice<const int> s = {xs.begin(), xs.size()};
```

In C++17, if you add an appropriate constructor or a deduction guide, you can omit the template argument.

```
template <typename T>
Slice(T* ptr, std::size_t len) -> Slice<T>;

Slice s = {xs.begin(), xs.size()};
```

Comment: What's a deduction guide?

Comment: @JohnLeidegren https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction See in particular "User-defined deduction guides" section